# undefined symbol:_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTModelManager error on Xcode release build -React native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

**undefined symbol:_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTModelManager**

````
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTModalManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libReact-Core.a(RCTModalHostViewManager.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)```
````

Comment: Same error here, are you found any solution?

Comment: I have Downgraded the react native version at that time.